Find the integer sequence
The following integer sequence has come up in my research. For a given $n$, it counts the number of independent entries in some (correlation) matrix of size $(2n+1)^6$.
f(1) = 20
f(2) = 165
f(3) = 816
f(4) = 2925
f(5) = 8436
f(6) = 20825

I am trying to come up with a generic formula, but nothing has worked so far.

Could you add more details about how the sequence is constructed? It's often hard / impossible to "guess" a sequence from the first few terms.

Unfortunately, the matrix (of size $(2n+1)^6$) which I am using is constructed more or less from a "black-box" function. I look for the number of unique entries in this matrix, which is where the sequence comes from. I will try to add more terms.

You can use Lagrange interpolation to find a formula, though it will likely be incorrect and overfit onto your data. Simply using this online calculator I got:
$$f(x)=\frac{9 x^5}{2}-\frac{157 x^4}{6}+\frac{767 x^3}{6}-\frac{1589 x^2}{6}+\frac{893 x}{3}-119$$

oeis doesn't recognize it.

With just a finite sequence of outputs, predicting the next number in the sequence is impossible.  There is a reasonable explanation for any number to come next.  Without more information regarding the process that generates this, you won't get a definitive answer.

@lulu though if you divide each term by $n+1$ (perhaps not a coincidence that this gives integers), OEIS then suggests multiplying by $6$ to get OEIS A120573

@Henry  Good catch

The numbers are all tetrahedral numbers.
Multiply each number by $6$ to get a product $a$ and take the cube root of $a$ rounded up to the next integer to get $b$. If $a+b=b^3$ you have a tetrahedral number and it will be of the form
$(b-1)b(b+1)/6$.
Thus
$20×6=120=a$
$\text{Rounded }\sqrt[3]{120}=5=b$
$a+b=125=5^3 ☆$
$20=(\color{blue}{4}×5×6)/6$
$165×6=990=a$
$\text{Rounded }\sqrt[3]{990}=10=b$
$a+b=1000=10^3 ☆$
$165=(\color{blue}{9}×10×11)/6$
And so on. In each case the argument in blue is a square and we then render
$f(n)=(n+1)^2[(n+1)^2+1][(n+1)^2+2]/6$
$=(n^6+6n^5+18n^4+32n^3+35n^2+22n+6)/6$

There are many possible answers.
One it that it looks similar to $\frac16n^2(n^2+1)(n^2+2)$, which looks potentially simple,
except that you need to use $n+1$ rather than n, so
$$f(n)=\frac{(n+1)^2\big((n+1)^2+1\big)\big((n+1)^2+2\big)}{6} \\= \frac{(n^2+2n+1)(n^2+2n+2)(n^2+2n+3)}{6}.$$

Not squaring the quadratic factors, maybe?

@OscarLanzi Yes - thank you - edited
